# MlflowException: The specified input argument index (1) is out of range for the function signature: 1

Tags: python, databricks, mlflow

I am trying to use the "predict" method in a model I pickled and logged using MLFlow. When I load it the predict function doesn't work.
I set it like this:

```
artifacts = {
        "estimator" : "/tmp/fitted_model.pkl",
    }

    input_schema = Schema([
        ColSpec("float", "input1"),
        ColSpec("float", "input2"),
        ColSpec("float", "input3"),
        ColSpec("float", "input4"),
        ColSpec("float", "input5"),
        ColSpec("float", "input6"),
        ColSpec("float", "input7"),
        ColSpec("float", "input8"),
    ])
    output_schema = Schema([
        ColSpec("float", "output"),
    ])
    signature = ModelSignature(inputs=input_schema, outputs=output_schema)
            
    model_info = mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
        artifact_path='model',
        registered_model_name="model_name",
        artifacts=artifacts,
        python_model=model,
        signature=signature,
    )
```

The model is a mlflow.pyfunc PythonModel.
I used "predict" before logging it and it works, I have no idea what is going on...